# Сортировка таблицы по количеству населения React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Нужно отсортировать таблицу по строке популяция, данные приходят с API, я их "вытащил" через axios, таблица отображается, но не знаю как отсортировать данные, которые приходят извне, а не статические.Вот мой код

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
      super(props)
      this.state={
          countries:[],

      }
  }
  componentDidMount(){
      axios.get('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all')
      .then(response => {
          this.setState({
              countries:response.data 
          })
      })
      .catch((error) => {
          console.log("error", error)
      })
  }

  render(){
      return(

          <div className = 'table'>

          <table>
          <tbody>
          <tr>
          <th>Country name </th>
          <th>Currencies</th>
          <th>Region </th>
          <th>Flag </th>
          <th>Population</th>
          <th>Languages</th>

          </tr>
          {
              this.state.countries.map((country) => {
                  return(

                      <tr className="tableRow">
                     <td> {country.name}</td>
                     <td>{country.currencies.map((currency,i)=>{
                     return (

                     <p>
                         <span>{currency.name} </span>

                         <span>{currency.symbol} </span>
                         </p>

                     )
                     })} </td>
                     <td> {country.region}</td>
                     <td> <img src={country.flag} alt={country.denonym}/> </td>
                     <td> {country.population} </td>
                     <td> {country.languages.map((language)=>{
                     return (
                         <span> {language.name} </span>
                     )
                     })} </td>
                      </tr>

                  )
              })
          }
          </tbody>

          </table>
          </div>

      )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно заменить `this.state.countries.map`

на

`sortBy(this.state.countries, c => c.population).map`

и добавить сверху файла:

`const sortBy = require('lodash/sortBy');`

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное, заработало.А можно это сделать при клике?Чтобы при клике на population оно сортировало таблицу.Заранее Вам благодарен

Comment: Надеюсь вы не будете против, если я вам дам удочку, вместо рыбы. На каждый хедер таблицы нужно повесть событие onClick. Событие (ну точнее обработчик) должно делать setState и записывать туда, в стейт, какое поле было только что нажато. Далее в функции рендер, где в sortBy вы считываете из стейта поле для сортировки, и подставляете его в sortBy вместо population.

Comment: Потом, когда у вас всё это заработает (а если нет - пишите, разберёмся), возможно будет разумно посмореть на гитхабе готовые компоненты для вывода подобных таблиц. Таблицы такого рода обычно называются datatable. Но это если нужен доп. функционал

Comment: как я понимаю, это нужно сделать если нужно сортировать всю таблицу, по каждому полю, а мне нужно чтобы только population сортировала, остальные поля не нужны.Рыба, вместо удочки, это больше, чем я мог рассчитывать, за что Вам спасибо.

Comment: в общем вы правы, практика показывает, что лучше делать сразу наверняка. мне кажется, что после того как сортировка при клике заработает, вам захочется, чтобы при повторном клике сортировало в обратно порядке, и при новом клике - сбрасывало сортировку. можно ещё множественную сортировку сделать. ну если что - заливайте на codesandbox.io , удачи

Comment: Приветствую. Ну как, получилось? И тикните галочку пожалуйста, спасибо

Comment: Доброе утро, к сожалению не получилось.У меня есть готовое решение, но хочется самому прийти к этому, а не копировать то, что мне скинули.Я не могу дойти в своей голове к тому, что должен обновлять метод, который будет записан в onClick строки Population.Ведь переменной country еще нет, а переменная countries это обычный массив.Как перебрать строку Population, если {country.population} ещё не существует

Comment: приветствую! метод должен менять состояние компонента (setState) таком образом, чтобы вы считав это состояние в рендери могли определить надо ли сортировать массив перед тем как возвращать .map() от него

Comment: поэтому я кстати и описал сверху алгоритм для сортировки по любому полю, потому что в итоге расход сил получается тот же самый. ну то есть просто меняете state, сообщая ему что надо сортировать по полю такому то. в рендере смотрите надо ли сортировать и сортируете если надо. в общем если будут вопросы - пишите

Comment: кстати говоря, полностью поддерживаю ваше стремление сделать самому, а не использовать готовое решение